# Trying to create an environment of verbatim with background, but it won't compile?

Tags: environments

I am trying to create my own verbatim environment with a background color, but for some reason it doesn't compile (for various reasons I would like to use my own macro):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myspverbatim}{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red]\begin{verbatim}}{\end{verbatim}\end{mdframed}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myspverbatim}
doesn't work?
\end{myspverbatim}

\end{document}
```

I can't understand why.

Error:

```
 Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \next. <inserted
 text> 
                 \par
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `\begin{verbatim}` like that (and it's explained in the manual of `verbatim`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{myspverbatim}
 {\mdframed[backgroundcolor=red!90!green]\verbatim}
 {\endverbatim\endmdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{myspverbatim}
doesn't work?
\end{myspverbatim}

\end{document}
```

You may want to use `fancyvrb`, much more flexible than `verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{myspverbatim}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red!90!green]% <-- no pure color
  \begin{Verbatim}%
}{\end{Verbatim}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myspverbatim}
doesn't work?
\end{myspverbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tcolorbox package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{myspverbatim}{colback=red,listing only}

\begin{document}

\begin{myspverbatim}
doesn't work?
\end{myspverbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, I prefer to use a verbatim style environment, but this is an excellent solution.