# newenvironment with enviromentS (plural) inside

Tags: environments, memoir, verbatim, mdframed, ntheorem

I'm trying to create an environment for a particular class (based on memoir) I'm doing. I followed this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_DQnSXLHBc) besides Overleaf basic tutorials on creating a new environment but I simply do not know what the problem (besides me...) is.

Codes defined in the .cls file:
(1) for having examples with counters:

```
\RequirePackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\ast}}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{exemplo}{\textsc{Exemplo}}
```

(2) for a specific type of box with mdframed:

```
\newenvironment{bxblack}
{\begin{mdframed}
        [skipabove=7pt,
        skipbelow=7pt,
        rightline=false,
        leftline=true,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        backgroundcolor=black!5,
        linecolor=black,
        innerleftmargin=5pt,
        innerrightmargin=5pt,
        innertopmargin=5pt,
        innerbottommargin=5pt,
        leftmargin=0cm,
        rightmargin=0cm,
        linewidth=5pt]}
    {\end{mdframed}}
```

(3) for verbatim (not in the class, but in the .tex file)

```
\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}
```

My attemp was to make this:

```
\newenvironment{bxexvrb}{
\begin{exemplo}
    \begin{bxblack}
        \begin{verbatim}  
        Text Text Text
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{bxblack}
\end{exemplo}
}
```

so every time I invoke \begin{bxexvrb} ... \end{bxexvrb} the text that goes inside the environ. would be:

1. numbered with auto counter (Example 1, Example 2, Example 3, etc)
2. in a framed box (with specific config as above)
3. the text in verbatim

in order to produce this (the image below is when I use all the environments separately):

[image]

The code for the pic. above:

```
\begin{exemplo}
    \begin{bxblack}
        \begin{verbatim}
        Valor1 = 3
        Valor2 = 4
        Valor3 = 9
        Some(valor1 + valor2 + valor3)
        Multiplique(Some * 32)
        Imprima: Multiplique
        Imprima: (Multiplique)
        Imprima: (Multiplique + Esse é seu número da sorte e 
        você deve jogar na loteria 
        para ganhar o grande prêmio).
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{bxblack}
\end{exemplo}
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything else in the class compiles smoothly, including the environments above when run separatley (but not altogether as I am trying to do).

Comment: Have a look for `\newtcblisting` from the tcolorbox package. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668665/trying-to-create-an-environment-of-verbatim-with-background-but-it-wont-compil/668676#668676

Comment: Thanks. It was not what I was looking for but I figured it out after the hint.